# How to embed HTML5/CSS + js music player on single wordpress page?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, audio

I have an html 5, css, and javascript audio player that I'm trying to add to one page on my wordpress site.

I tried to paste the html into my page's text editor, while installing the JS and CSS folders for the player in my child theme's folder, which didn't work.

I tried placing the CSS for the player styling in my child themes CSS file, and that didn't work. I also tried linking to the style sheets and js scripts from the header.php file, which wasn't working for me.

My first thoughts are that because the html is showing up as it should, the css and JS files aren't being called. So I just need to figure out the path structure of how wordpress creates pages? Yet I know wordpress does something with a database to display the pages?

I saw some documentation about using I think it was either php or JS functions to call scripts or something and I don't understand enough of those languages to be able to make sense of it yet.

I'm still working with my developer, but he's 7 hours ahead of me and asleep. I just want to put the hardcoded version of the player and a few songs on my site for now so I can do some testing/see how it looks.

I hope that this question meets the SO req's. I tried to search on my own and I know the answer is out there, I just don't know enough to understand it yet. Trying to get a head start

Answer (score 0):

The path to your Child theme's folder should be '/wp-content/themes/*name-of-theme*/'.  You can use that in your header to call the files from wherever you might have placed them in your Child theme's folder.

To hard code the HTML, pasting it in the WordPress page editor should work fine unless there is another JS call or some weird iFraming going on.. if that's the case, you can simply create a Page Template (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use) and paste the code there.  You'll likely want to just copy an existing page template from your Theme, take out the inner loop, and replace it with your video code.

Adding the links to your 'header.php' file would be considered bad practice.  You would want to create a 'functions.php' file inside your Child theme and call the JS/CSS from there.  You can also find this within the WordPress codex (they literally give examples you can copy/paste and change your file names).

Comment: I added all my projects files to my child theme's directory, then added a functions.php file to the directory as well. That broke that page on my site. I will include the php below

Comment: `<?php
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js' );
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/player.js' );
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/style.css' );
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/fonts.css' );
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/fonts/icomoon.eot' );
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/fonts/icomoon.svg' );
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/fonts/icomoon.ttf' );
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/fonts/icomoon.woff' );
`

Comment: I already see I should have enqued the style and scripts, not that.

Can I enque the font files the same way as I would a style sheet? Or wil enqueing the style sheet be enough to find the fonts?

Comment: `<?php

wp_enqueue_style( 'css/style.css', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_style( 'css/fonts.css', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/player.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
`

Thats my updated php code, but it's still not applying any style or js to the player on my site's page.